# run bash command in python script and make sure it runs

Tags: python, windows, bash, jupyter

I wanted to run a bash script with Python.

```
bash download.sh
```

I got

> name 'bash' is not defined

I tried this code again:

```py
import os
starting = os.popen('bash download.sh')
starting.read()
```

I received: `''`

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I' m using jupyter on Windows

Comment: `bash` is not a standard command on Windows.

Comment: You'll need WSL or something similar to get `bash` going. Python doesn't include it, it's a function of your shell/environment.

Comment: sorry but what is WSL?  and how and i use it?

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) lets developers install a Linux distribution and use Linux applications, utilities, and Bash command-line tools directly on Windows.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Comment: I did the instalattion of WSL but how now i could use the bash command in python?

Comment: It's working i run the command